# Wrapping StyledText: force to not wrap words

Tags: java, swt

How can I tell `StyledText` created with the `SWT.WRAP` style to not wrap within words (it should only wrap on spaces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `StyledText` **does** only wrap on whitespace. Only when a single word is too long for a line, then it does in fact wrap within a word. But there's nothing else that could be done in that case.

Comment: Well, generally you add wrapping because you don't want horizontal scrollbars.

Comment: I use autowrapping to show continues text to the user. In that text, e.g. file names/paths or URLs should not be wrapped, but rather make the control wider.